# Email load custom php with variable strict mode - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

Since Magento 2.3.4 email variable usage was deprecated. See: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html

But we are using a email variable to load a custom php template, that loads specific values based on the payment method and customer group of the customer.

We load it at the moment like:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" order=$order name="order_payment" template="Magento_Sales::email/paymentmethod.phtml" area="frontend"}}
```

And inside the `paymentmethod.phtml` we load the following php values, but these will not work anymore. Because it is not pushing the order anymore to the `paymentmethod.phtml`.

```
$order = $this->getData('order');
$orderid = $order->getId();
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
$methodTitle = $method->getTitle();
```

But this will not work anymore in 2.4.4, so we need to modify this.

How can we still load this custom php, that checks the payment method and customer group of the customer and then load a specific text line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your email template you need to use

```
{{block class="..." order_id=$order_id name="..." template="..." area="frontend"}}
```

I suggest to create additional block class instead of use `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` and inject `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` or you can try to reuse `\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items` just for receive order instance (for order and related blocks for other sales entities).

With block `\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items` you can use following in your template:

```
$order = $block->getOrder();
$orderid = $order->getId();
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
$methodTitle = $method->getTitle();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect. Any idea how to get the customer first name in the e-mail? The old method does not work anymore: `{{trans "%name," name=$order.getBillingAddress().getFirstname()}}`

Comment: You need to create observer for event `email_order_set_template_vars_before` and extend `transportObject` data. Just add `customer_firstname` into `order_data` and use like `$order_data.customer_firstname`.

Comment: Thanks again! Last question, any idea how to solve my latest question? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358609/delivery-date-in-order-email-template-magento-2-4-3-p2