# Delivery date in order email template - Magento 2.4.3-p2

Tags: magento2, order-email, delivery-date

Previously, we used the following module to load the email variable with a custom CreatedAt value. Because this is deprecated, it will not work anymore (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html).

How can we modify the following, to keep using this custom CreatedAt from Magento 2.4.3-p2?

> app/code/Mago/Delivery/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Mago_Delivery',
__DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Mago/Delivery/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mago_Delivery" setup_version="1.0.1">
   </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Mago/Delivery/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order" type="Mago\Delivery\Model\Rewrite\Order" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Mago/Delivery/Model/Rewrite/Order.php

```
<?php

namespace Mago\Delivery\Model\Rewrite;

class Order extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
{

    public function getDeliveryDate()
    {
        $orderDate = $this->getCreatedAt(); //ORDER CREATED DATE
        return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($orderDate. ' + 10 days'));
    }

}
```

Finally in your email template you can get this date by:

**{{var order.getDeliveryDate()}}**

EDIT, new code with Order, Invoice and Creditmemo:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo;

class OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected TimezoneInterface $timezone;
    protected string            $locale;

    public function __construct(
        TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        ResolverInterface $localeResolver
    ) {
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
        $this->locale   = $localeResolver->getLocale();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer): void
    {
        /** @var DataObject $transport */
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getData('transportObject');
        /** @var Order $order */
        $order     = $transport->getData('order');
        $orderData = $transport->getData('order_data');        
        /** @var Invoice $invoice */
        $invoice    = $transport->getData('invoice');
        $invoiceData = $transport->getData('invoice_data');
        /** @var Creditmemo $creditmemo */
        $creditmemo    = $transport->getData('creditmemo');
        $creditmemoData = $transport->getData('creditmemo_data');        

        $orderDate = new \DateTime($order->getCreatedAt(), new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $orderData['order_date'] = $this->timezone->formatDateTime(
            $orderDate,
            \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
            \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
            $this->locale
        );
        $transport->setData('order_data', $orderData);
        
        if($invoice){     
            $invoiceDate = new \DateTime($invoice->getCreatedAt(), new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
            $invoiceData['invoice_date'] = $this->timezone->formatDateTime(
                $invoiceDate,
                \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
                \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
                $this->locale
            );
            $transport->setData('invoice_data', $invoiceData);
        }
        
        if($creditmemo){     
            $creditmemoDate = new \DateTime($creditmemo->getCreatedAt(), new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
            $creditmemoData['creditmemo_date'] = $this->timezone->formatDateTime(
                $creditmemoDate,
                \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
                \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
                $this->locale
            );
            $transport->setData('creditmemo_data', $creditmemoData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the same logic described in comment https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358427/91782

I don't recommend to rewrite models such Order just for get some value for email template.

You need to create observer for event `email_order_set_template_vars_before`, or you can use the same observer for prepare any required data and using `transportObject` add custom variables to `order_data`.

You can use `order` object from `transportObject` as current order

You also can cover following events (if needed):

- `email_order_comment_set_template_vars_before`
- `email_invoice_set_template_vars_before`
- `email_invoice_comment_set_template_vars_before`
- `email_shipment_set_template_vars_before`
- `email_shipment_comment_set_template_vars_before`
- `email_creditmemo_set_template_vars_before`
- `email_creditmemo_comment_set_template_vars_before`

You can use single observer for all events because all of them are has `order` instance and `order_data` which you can extend for templates.

**[Update]**

It's easy to create separate module (extension) and you already provided an example in your answer, but I will repeat

**1. Create Registration module file**

`app/code/Acme/SalesEmail/registration.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Acme_SalesEmail', __DIR__);
```

Where `Acme` is your vendor name and `SalesEmail` is module name

**2. Define module and dependencies**

`app/code/Acme/SalesEmail/etc/module.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Acme_SalesEmail">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**3. Register observers to events**

`app/code/Acme/SalesEmail/etc/events.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="acme_salesemail_observer_email_order_set_template_vars_before"
                  instance="Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email\OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore"/>
    </event>
    <event name="email_order_comment_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="acme_salesemail_observer_email_order_comment_set_template_vars_before"
                  instance="Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email\OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore"/>
    </event>
    <event name="email_invoice_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="acme_salesemail_observer_email_invoice_set_template_vars_before"
                  instance="Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email\OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore"/>
    </event>
    <event name="email_invoice_comment_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="acme_salesemail_observer_email_invoice_comment_set_template_vars_before"
                  instance="Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email\OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore"/>
    </event>
    <event name="email_shipment_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="acme_salesemail_observer_email_shipment_set_template_vars_before"
                  instance="Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email\OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore"/>
    </event>
    <event name="email_shipment_comment_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="acme_salesemail_observer_email_shipment_comment_set_template_vars_before"
                  instance="Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email\OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore"/>
    </event>
    <event name="email_creditmemo_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="acme_salesemail_observer_email_creditmemo_set_template_vars_before"
                  instance="Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email\OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore"/>
    </event>
    <event name="email_creditmemo_comment_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="acme_salesemail_observer_email_creditmemo_comment_set_template_vars_before"
                  instance="Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email\OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**4. Create universal observer**

`app/code/Acme/SalesEmail/Observer/Email/OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore.php`

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\SalesEmail\Observer\Email;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected TimezoneInterface $timezone;
    protected string            $locale;

    public function __construct(
        TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        ResolverInterface $localeResolver
    ) {
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
        $this->locale   = $localeResolver->getLocale();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer): void
    {
        /** @var DataObject $transport */
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getData('transportObject');
        /** @var Order $order */
        $order     = $transport->getData('order');
        $orderData = $transport->getData('order_data');

        $billing   = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $orderData['customer_firstname'] = $billing->getFirstname();
        $orderData['customer_lastname']  = $billing->getLastname();

        $deliveryDate = new \DateTime($order->getCreatedAt(), new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $deliveryDate->add(new \DateInterval('P10D'));

        $orderData['delivery_date'] = $this->timezone->formatDateTime(
            $deliveryDate,
            \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
            \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
            $this->locale
        );

        $transport->setData('order_data', $orderData);
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

You can use [Generator Tool](https://mage2gen.com/) for create some skeleton of code

[image]

Comment: Thanks Victor! Can you help me out with the right custom module code? So we can implement it as a custom module?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how can we load it correct in the e-mail template then?

Comment: In the same way: `{{var order_data.customer_firstname}}` or `{{trans "%firstname," firstname=$order_data.customer_firstname}}`

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks a lot! Seems that we face another issue, because we also used our module to change the CreatedAt() date for the Invoice and Credit. Is there an easier way to override the default `/Sales/Model/Order.php` and `/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php` and `/Sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo.php` files, to change the format of the getCreatedAt() value?

Comment: As I've pointed in my answer, I don't suggest to rewrite Order, Invoice or Creditmemo with preference for do something for email. You can add custom logic to observer and check if transport has `invoice` just made something additional with invoice data, etc

Comment: Thanks again! Well, problem is that we do not only use it in the email, but also in the PDF for invoice, shipment etc. So we also do need to get the invoice CreatedAt value. How can we implement that? Is there a easy way to implement it like `{{var invoice_data.customer_firstname}}`?

Comment: You can register `invoice_data` array for transport and populate it if `invoice` present. After you can use like `{{var invoice_data.customer_firstname}}`. Please see example and check transport object. You can find in core code by event name what the system pass into transport. You can use any variable which are you set into transport in template.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, can you check my edit, where we added the Invoice and Creditmemo values also. This should be right and working well?