# How to add a Name variable from Billing or Shipping address?

Tags: magento2

I need to use a Name from Billing or Shipping Address in an order confirmation email.

I tried several ways but none of them work…

It's Magento 2.4.1

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use firstname or full name from billing?

Anyway, I've described how to extend order data for emails in neighboring topic:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358613/91782

You can add additional data in example observer

Comment: Both will work for me, first name or full name, doesn't matter. Thanks! Will check it out.

Comment: I hope you checked the mentioned answer and it helped

Comment: Yes, I just tried and it helped! Thanks a lot!