# Get orderId into email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I have created module to get order_id to get some custom information from database.

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
    <observer name="add_custom_variable_to_Order"
              instance="Customedit\GetOrder\Observer\ObserverforAddCustomVariable"/>
</event>
```

**ObserverforAddCustomVariable.php**

```
namespace Customedit\GetOrder\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
class ObserverforAddCustomVariable implements ObserverInterface
{

  public function __construct()
  {
  }
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $transport = $observer->getTransport();
    $order = $transport->getOrder()->getId();
    $transport['Get_OrderId'] = $order;
  }
}
```

Now, I want to check that I can get orderId with

```
{{var Get_OrderId}}
```

it returned nothing.

Did I use wrong method or did something wrong?

If I can't get order_id. Can I get increment_id instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using correct event for process email templates for new order

See some notes and example in https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358613/91782

If you want to operate order data better to extend and use `order_data` array.

The Order ID is already present in template and you can use following to render it in template

```
{{var order_id}}
```

Comment: kindly can you take a look here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359058/magento2-4-2-how-to-display-only-those-payment-method-options-in-filter-in-sale