# Shipping information block and customer email

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, email-templates, order-email

I'm relatively new to Magento development and we're currently using version 2.4.5-p1.

We recently migrated from Magento 1 and I'm now working on customizing the new order email. So far, I've encountered two issues.

Initially, the order created date variable wasn't functioning. However, after some online research, I used the variable **`{{var created_at_formatted}}`**, which now correctly displays the order date. So that issue has been resolved.

However, I'm currently experiencing an issue with our shipping information. We have a block similar to this one:

```
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                               {{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}
                                 
                            </td>
```

This block displays the shipping information correctly, such as the name, address, and phone number. However, the customer's email field is empty. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can populate this field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Magento by default does not include email address information in the Shipping Address section on the email template. The template displays only the Name, Company Name, Address, and Phone fields.

Please confirm if you intend to customize the template to meet your specific requirements.

Comment: Hello yes that is correct we are customising the template and we wanted to include the email address bellow the telephone number.

Comment: @Sam kindly ask the new question related to this, so you will get what you are looking. If my above answer help you, accept as solution and upvote, so it will help other into community as well.

Comment: Hi @Dhiren Vasoya. Not sure I understand your last commend. You asked me a question if im customizing the templates and i said yes. Still I'm not sure how to include the email id there..

Comment: To added extra fields into email temaplte, you can check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358609/delivery-date-in-order-email-template-magento-2-4-3-p2/358613#358613